# 2 or more web servers share one static ip

Tags: web-hosting, fqdn

I got 1 static Ip from my ISP.
I got  2 NS (from NS provider)pointing my domain name towards my wan IP. 
My question: How do I get server1.domainname.td to reach server 1 inside my network, server2.domainname.td to reach server 2
also placed on my local network(server1 =192.168.1.2 and server2=192.168.1.3) both with use of port 80 only (no portforwarding) (server1=ms win server2=Linux)
Second question: How to reach server3.domainname.td on a server placed outside my network ( another static ip on the internet)

Comment: For web traffic you typically run a reverse proxy (such as haproxy, but also most webservers can be configured as such, nginx and apache certainly can) on ports 80 and 443 of  your single ip-address. The reverse proxy can be configured to map all requests for one URL to one (or more) specific back-end server(s) and all requests for a second URL to a second (group of) back-end server(s). i.e. `www.example.com/a` gets mapped to server-a and `www.example.com/b` to server-b.  Alternatively the mapping goes by (sub-)domains i.e. map ` www.a.example.com` to server-a etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will tryout nginx. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one IP address (hence one port `80` and `443`) you need to use a **reverse proxy** like **nginx** to forward requests to the appropriate internal server.

You need to add an `A` DNS record for `server1.example.com` and `server2.example.com` pointing to your public address.

The **nginx** server might be running on your gateway if you have a good router with [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/webserver/nginx) firmware or a professional router with proxy capabilities. Otherwise you need to use one of the internal servers and set up a port forwarding from the router to the internal server.

There are a lot of tutorials online on how to configure [nginx as reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/).

Remark that this configuration will be slow and prone to failure. For a professional deployment use an external web hosting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try with nginx. 

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned with web traffic (port 443 or port 80), as others have suggested, use nginx. It's very lightweight. It is what I do.

Assuming linux, in /etc/nginx create a file for your network (eg proxy.conf):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  server1.domainname.td;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
    }
}
```

create this stanza in a file (say...route.conf) and place it under /etc/nginx (I assume linux) Add as many stanzas as necessary for your purposes. In /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, include it:

```
include /etc/nginx/route.conf  (do this before the closing bracket)
```

As for server3, change proxy_pass to your hostname or ip:

```
proxy_pass http://youroutsideserver ..
```

**UPDATE**: 
As Piotr indicated, place your route.conf file in /etc/nginx/sites-available and symlink to your sites-enabled directory

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/router.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Comment: Most distributions already have many `include` directives in the default config file. On Debianoids, e.g., you can place your snippet in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory (or in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and symlink to the `sites-enabled` directory).

Comment: Very true. It always helps to double check. I updated the answer to include your input.